# Como acceder a el valor de un input en el admin de Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Tengo un modelo que se gestiona por el administrador de django, en el admin.py cree un método que agrega algunos campos del modelo a la propiedad readonly_fields cuando ya se ha creado el objeto, osea que cuando ingreso a modificar el objeto me aparecen los campos de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj:  # editing an existing object
        return self.readonly_fields + ('tipo_documento', 'num_documento', 'nombres', 'apellidos')
    return self.readonly_fields
```

ahora necesito hacer un condicional para saber si existe un valor en uno de los campos para añadirlo a la propiedad readonly_fields, ya intente con la siguiente condición pero no funciono

```
if obj.nombre_campo:
    return self.readonly_fields + ('otro_campo')
```

básicamente necesito saber como accedo a los valores de un input para poder hacer la condición

los campos que quiero agregar a readonly_fields siempre y cuando tengan valores son los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes enseñar que tienes en el template?

Comment: Hola @YoelMaciaDelgado, ya edite la pregunta

Comment: Entiendo que si `obj.nombre_campo` tiene datos (no está vacío), entonces quieres agregarlo a los `readonly_fields`, ¿es correcto?

Comment: Hola @César, eso es exactamente lo que quiero hacer